# Xamarin Forms - ListView - Array - Header

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Im working with the ListView component and I would like to set categories which makes use of the Header within a ListView.

The content I have is a list of events that are happening today, tomorrow and the next day

How would I go about adding that to a list

My code so far is below

```
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>Event 1 - Today</x:String>
                    <x:String>Event 2 - Today</x:String>
                    <x:String>Event 3 - Today</x:String>
                    <x:String>Event 4 - Today</x:String>
                    <x:String>Event 1 - Tomorrow</x:String>
                    <x:String>Event 2 - Tomorrow</x:String>
                    <x:String>Event 3 - Tomorrow</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
            <ListView.Header>
                <Label Text="Today"/>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource listViewRacecourse}" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I just have no clue how to get two values within the array, and then split them into two groups using ListView headers.

This is just a POC so I don't have a DB with all the content, hence not using a API or connection to a DB.

Comment: use Grouping - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping

Comment: How would that work with an Array? I cant see an example?

Comment: you need to build some mock data in code, not in the XAML

Comment: Damn, I was hoping it would be able to get away without that.

Comment: it would take 5 minutes to do this

Comment: You want to use a List or an ObservableCollection.

At the risk of sounding like I'm advertising someone's product, Syncfusion has a nice Listview control that does a really good job of grouping with formatting headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About ListView Group, Jason have provided one article about detailed info. If you still have some problem, you can also take a look the following sample.

Firstly, create class to hold event info.

```
public class eventmodel
{
    public string eventname { get; set; }
}
```

Then, a way to group the data, with a heading for each list.

```
 public class eventlist:List<eventmodel>
{
    public string heading { get; set; }
    public List<eventmodel> events => this;
}
```

Finally, using [Observablecollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0) to bind to listview. Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

```
public class eventgroup
{
    public ObservableCollection<eventlist> eventgroups { get; set; }
    public eventgroup()
    {
        eventgroups = new ObservableCollection<eventlist>();

        var list1 = new eventlist()
        {
            new eventmodel() { eventname= "Event 1 - Today" },
            new eventmodel() { eventname= "Event 2 - Today" },
            new eventmodel() { eventname= "Event 3 - Today" },
            new eventmodel() { eventname= "Event 4 - Today" }
                                                         
        };
        list1.heading = "Today";
        var list2 = new eventlist()
        {
            new eventmodel() { eventname= "Event 1 - Tomorrow" },
            new eventmodel() { eventname= "Event 2 - Tomorrow" },
            new eventmodel() { eventname= "Event 3 - Tomorrow" },
            new eventmodel() { eventname= "Event 4 - Tomorrow" } 
        };
        list2.heading = "Tomorrow";

        eventgroups.Add(list1);
        eventgroups.Add(list2);

       
    }
}
```

ListView displaying data.

```
<ListView IsGroupingEnabled="true" ItemsSource="{Binding eventgroups}">
            <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label BackgroundColor="Red" Text="{Binding heading}" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding eventname}" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

 public partial class Page6 : ContentPage
{
    public Page6()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new eventgroup();
    }
}
```

The screenshot:

[image]